# How to resize and position SwiperJS containers?

Tags: javascript, position, containers, height, swiper.js

I want the DIV at top of screen, say 100px high.

Horizontal Swiper under it with a calc'ed height 100% - 100px, resizing with window.
A second 'absolute' horizontal Swiper with specific height and width.

I've tried every combination of CSS, HTML and options on the new Swiper declarations for hours. DIV's around the containers. Positioning. I'm out of ideas. And yes, I've read the API over and over. I've dissected their samples. Height adjustments on container, wrapper, slides, content.
Width does not seem to be an issue.
Height games will make the container vanish, or add extra space to bottom, or cease function, or all kinds of funny stuff.

At this point, prove I'm an idiot with boilerplate working code, PLEASE..!

Technically, the goal is any number of Swiper containers that I can position and resize as needed. Seems simple but I'm exhausted. I'd estimate I've tried well over a hundred combos in code over six hours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] showing the code you have now. That will provide a basis for people to give you answers that relate to how you've set up the page rather than based on how you described the page.

Comment: As  stated, many many "codes" and nothing works. I even scrapped my page and started with boilerplate testbed as described to eliminate "interference"... same problems. I'll try to recreate it and send the testbed soon...